# wxWidgets transparent background image?

Tags: wxpython, transparency, wxwidgets

I'm attempting to create a window with a transparent PNG background with no success, how would I go about it? Setting `wx.Frame.SetShape` allows for non-box shapes, but transparency effects like shadows still have a background behind them.

For example, the [Photoshop splash screen](http://line-in.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Dreamweaver_splash_screen-620x427.jpg).

Comment: This might help http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/

Comment: That example still has a solid window background. I'm looking to make the background completely transparent and then draw an image on it.

Comment: Im not certain but I think that will work with transparent PNG also, he mentions using same at the end of the article, its worth a shot -wouldn't take long to test out.

Comment: Just noticed  and looked at splash screen you linked to. I thought you were interested in a transparent background image on a panel, what you want to do is completely different, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking at some of the threads about transparency effects on the main wxPython mailing list. Ray Pasco had quite a thread on it last month. You might also look at Whyteboard (not sure if it does transparency or not) or the float canvas widgets (there are two of those). Heck, it's probably worth cross-posting to the main mailing list since that's where wxPython's creator hangs out.

Comment: Good memory, thanks very much for the nudge towards the mailing list. I found the thread you were talking about. http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.wxpython/79682/match=transparency